# how to attach a file and send a email using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a view to send   an email by attaching a file. I just started coding but not sure how to attach .could anybody help me for this.
here is my small code.

```
<div>
    <div> To</div>
    <div><input type="text" name="" placeholder=""  size="70" /></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Subject</div>
    <div><input type="text" name="" placeholder="" size="70"/></div>
</div>
```

after this I have to add image and by click that image I have to attach a file and enter message, then click send button.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [`ngDroplet`](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngDroplet) module.

Comment: Best way would be via `bower`: `bower install ng-droplet -S`